# How to pass build time config vars into container

Tags: docker, heroku

I have a multi-stage build, like so:

```
# Use a multi-stage build to handle the compiling, installing, etc.

# STAGE 1: Install node_modules on a stretch container
FROM node:10-stretch as base
ARG APP_DIR=/node
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
RUN chown node:node $APP_DIR
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
USER node
RUN ["npm", "install", "--no-optional"]
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# STAGE 2: Extend the base image as a builder image
FROM base as builder
ARG APP_NAME
ARG BASE_URL
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN npm run build -- --mode=production && rm -rf node_modules && npm install --no-optional --production

# STAGE 3: Copy the 'build' directory from previous stage and run in alpine
# Since this does not extend the base image, we need to set workdir, user, etc. again.
FROM node:10-alpine
ARG APP_DIR=/node
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node $APP_DIR/dist .
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node $APP_DIR/node_modules ./node_modules
USER node
CMD ["node", "./server"]
```

According to [this documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables) I should be able to define the `ARG` vars in my Dockerfile, and then supply values for them in my `heroku.yml`, but that seems not to be the case. If I hard code the value directly into my Dockerfile, it works - but that's not what I want to do (for obvious reasons). Am I missing something?

My `heroku.yml` looks like this:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    APP_NAME: Weeknight Cookbook
    BASE_URL: /
    NODE_ENV: production
```